# How to find run information of parent DAG from within a task in SUBDAG

Tags: airflow

I need to capture the execution_date, run_id, dag_id and list of failed tasks of the parent DAG within a task in subdag part of the parent DAG.
Explanation -
Suppose I have a DAG(DAG_A) which has a SUBDAG(SUBDAG_A).
A task in SUBDAG_A needs to capture the above information about DAG_A for the same current run. I tried the context variable but it gives info about the SUBDAG_A and not for DAG_A. How can I find the info of DAG_A from within SUBDAG_A ?

I am using airflow 1.10